# Apache Ignite: Failed to load job class [class=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.hadoop.v2.HadoopV2Job]

Tags: ignite

I am trying to start a server using the ignite.sh script and am getting the above error (failed to load HadoopV2Job). `"config/default-config.xml"` is being passed to CommandLineStartup and hasn't been changed.

Has anyone came across this issue or does anyone know how to fix it?

My Ignite version is 1.4.0 and here is the full stack trace:

```
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to start processor: HadoopProcessor [idCtr=0]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.convertException(IgniteUtils.java:881)
at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:349)
at org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:302)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start processor: HadoopProcessor [idCtr=0]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startProcessor(IgniteKernal.java:1504)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:888)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1617)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1484)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:965)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:892)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:784)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:705)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:576)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:546)
at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:346)
... 1 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to load job class [class=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.hadoop.v2.HadoopV2Job]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.hadoop.jobtracker.HadoopJobTracker.start(HadoopJobTracker.java:167)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.hadoop.HadoopProcessor.start(HadoopProcessor.java:103)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startProcessor(IgniteKernal.java:1501)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.hadoop.HadoopClassLoader.hasExternalDependencies(HadoopClassLoader.java:288)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.hadoop.HadoopClassLoader.loadClass(HadoopClassLoader.java:162)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.hadoop.jobtracker.HadoopJobTracker.start(HadoopJobTracker.java:163)
... 13 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shane, did you compile the Ignite code with JDK8 ?
It looks like the org.objectweb.asm library failed to parse class "org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.hadoop.v2.HadoopV2Job" bytecode because the bytecode version is higher than 1.7:

```
/**
 * Constructs a new {@link ClassReader} object.
 * 
 * @param b
 *            the bytecode of the class to be read.
 * @param off
 *            the start offset of the class data.
 * @param len
 *            the length of the class data.
 */
public ClassReader(final byte[] b, final int off, final int len) {
    this.b = b;
    // checks the class version
    if (readShort(off + 6) > Opcodes.V1_7) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
```

Please try to build Ignite witgh JDK 1.7 or specify target level = 1.7 with JDK8. Does that solve the problem?

Comment: Ivan, yes, it was compiled using JDK8. I have since reinstalled and am using the Ignite-hadoop binary which works.

Comment: As an update; references to jdk 1.8 are found in 'parent/pom.xml' and 'examples/pom.xml' under the "java8" profile. I tried commenting out this section but that produced other errors. What worked in the end was setting the source and target tags to 1.7 instead of commenting out the section.